# How to return Ajax data request by id in octobercms?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, octobercms

This has to be pretty straight forward by not sure how.

I am building a front end form with categories and subcategories. The code below displays the categories in select box without any issue

**Php block**

```
$this['items'] = Cat::where('parent_id',0)->pluck('cat_title', 'id');
```

**Display**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <b><label class="float-left" id="cats" 
for="inputCategory">Category</label></b>
  <select id="category" class="form-control" data-request="onChangeCat" 
 data-request-update="select: '#subcategory'">
    <option selected>Choose...</option>

    {% for key, item in items %}
    <option value={{ key }}> {{ item }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

  </select>
</div>
```

I have an data-request up there with the following Ajax handler to display subcategories in the next select-box. The partial to be rendered is also in place.

```
   function onChangeCat()
   {
   $this['subs'] = Cat::where('parent_id', '>',0)->pluck('cat_title', 'id');

    }
```

The question is how do i write the Ajax handler code to only display subcategories by id of the category. The code above just displays all the subcategories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Give your `select` a name tag `<select name="category">..</select>`
2. Query the subcategories with the posted data accessible via the `post()` function : e.g  `Cat::where('parent_id', '=', post('category') )->pluck('cat_title', 'id')`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a route that take as a parameter `selected` item on the category select, then that route will filter through sub-categories to have only related sub-categories, the you will send the result back as json using `json_encode()` take data and create options then add them to the sub-categories select.

The route will be called ones the user change the select category.

Comment: What do you mean by ajax handler ?